# Run JDBC program in UNIX

Tags: unix, jdbc

I want to run a sample JDBC program,I have run the program from eclipse and for this I used classes12.jar file, i want to run the same program in Unix, Do we need add any more jar files, and please tell the path where we need to add the jar files in unix and path where to add jDBC program .

Comment: The Oracle driver `classes12.jar` is **horribly** outdated. It was intended to be used with Java 1.2. Don't use it any more (unless you are indeed using Java 1.2). Current drivers are named `ojdbc6.jar` or `ojdbc7.jar` (indicating Java 6 and Java 7)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, can you please for running JDBC program where is the path to keep the java program and jar files, and command to run java file in UNnix

Comment: You put the files wherevery you like. Just as with any other .jar file. You just need to make sure to include them by e.g. specifying the `-cp` parameter to the `java` command when you start your application.

Comment: In unix in some x folder, i kepy my jdbc file, i login into unix through putty , went to x folder and run the command javac -cp OracleJDBC.java . its saying no source files found, when I do ls, its showing java file ..please suggest what is wrong here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should may be go through JDBC tutorials and execution of java in linux/unix environment.

JDBC tut like this one http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/index.htm

You will need only JDBC jar additional to your own class

-cp option is to load jars to the class path. Please check how to set classpath

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html

Your java execution will be something like

> java -cp PATH_TO_JARS className

suppose you have placed your ojdbc jar at a directory path /home/alpha/dbconn/lib and as mentioned by you the classname to be OracleJDBC, then the call will be something like below

> java -cp "/home/alpha/dbconn/lib/*" OracleJDBC